# struct.error: argument for 's' must be a string

Tags: python, authentication, raspberry-pi3, fingerprint

i'm working on a authentication system with raspberry pi with the Fingerprint Scanner - TTL (GT-511C3) and i have a function that create a template and returns as result the following :

[image]

I want to extract only th data part so i did like this : **response [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OAfY.png)['Data']**

but when i print it i get this :

[image]

i added this as header of my file :

```
reload(sys)  
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
```

and i tried a couple of solutions i found in the forum but i couldn't find one that works with me.

my problem is when i try to compare the created template with the ones already in the database of the scanner with a function called **IdentifyTemplate** and takes as a parameter a template it gives me the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "finger.py", line 169, in 
indetifyResponse = f.IdentifyTemplate(makeTemplateResponse)
File "/home/pi/Desktop/fingerpi/fingerpi/fingerpi.py", line 213, in 
IdentifyTemplate
if self.sendData(template, 498):
File "/home/pi/Desktop/fingerpi/fingerpi/fingerpi.py", line 53, in sendData
packet = encode_data_packet(data, data_len, device_id = self.device_id)
File "/home/pi/Desktop/fingerpi/fingerpi/base.py", line 72, in 
encode_data_packet
data # Data to be sent
struct.error: argument for 's' must be a string
```

i suspect that the problem is comming from that Data that i'm trying to print.
Any help is much appreciated. **My Python version is 2.7.13**

Comment: here's two lines to reproduce with Python 2.7.14
`import struct`
`struct.pack('>64sIIB{}s'.format(10), "blah", 4, 10, 0, 0xdeadbeef)`